# Where are the "hands-on Challenge"?

Tags: trailhead

I'm moving the first steps with Salesforce and I cannot find the "Hands-On Callenge"  for the trailhead playground that the [Getting Started with the Platform](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/force_com_dev_beginner/modules/starting_force_com/units/starting_intro#) tutorial refers to.

I've already created a developer profile.

Comment: are you logged into trailheads when you are at https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trails/force_com_dev_beginner/modules/starting_force_com/units/starting_intro# ?

Answer (score 2):

Challenges are the last section of any given trailhead; there are generally two types: multiple choice and hands-on. Hands-on challenges involve you logging in, doing some action (creating or updating code, fields, etc), and multiple-choice are just questions that you'll find the answers for in the text. You'll know it's a hands-on challenge because there will be a button to log in to your developer org. On the right-hand navigation menu, they will always be listed as just "Challenge".

Answer (score 2):

In order to access the hands-on challenges, you must be logged in to Salesforce Trailheads with the username you are using to complete them (usually related to a developer org).

You can then access the hands-on challenges at the end of different modules. (not all of them have hands-on challenges)

[image]